# why http request respose is not display in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am trying to use `http` in angular 2 .I make a service and call service from component .But I am didn't get response in component why ?

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/YBjCGtuxPdniZ8WEngm2?p=preview

```
moveToSecond(){
    this.main.getData().subscribe(p =>{
     console.log('test');
     console.log(p)
    })
```

Secondly

how to handle **error** in angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return body.data || { };
```

to

```
return body || { };
```

Comment: please share plunker

Comment: one more thing can we handle error ? in catch block if file is not found